# In USA, do I need a 220V to 110V voltage converter for my India 220V laptop?

Tags: power

I am going for my higher studies to USA. Since I am from India, my laptop, electric shaver and mobile charger all run on 220V.

Power rating of laptop charger:
65W (100V - 240V ~ 1.5A)

What are some good converters, that can run all the above mentioned appliances?

Comment: But your laptop charger already works from 100V to 240V, so why would you need a converter?

Comment: You will probbly only need a socket adapter. You will be fine with the tension (V).

Comment: @nsn This may not be correct, please check my answer for details.

Comment: You definitely don't need a 220V to 110V converter if you want to go from 110V to 220V.

Comment: That 220V to 110V converter, used in the USA, will likely produce 55V.

Answer (score 30):

No need for converters, your charger accepts anything form 100V to 240V. It is safe to use it anywhere in the world. Note that the output of AC-DC adapters will always be the same regardless of the input voltage.

Comment: It will only take a bit longer to charge, probably.

Comment: @Bernhard no, not in the case of AC-DC, the output will always be the same.

Comment: @MeNoTalk Take note that this is only true for devices made to operate on separate voltages and have power supplies designed for a range of voltages. This is not generally true for electric shavers, hair dryers etc. the charger as one might expect will say this on it, albeit in small letters. :)

Comment: @AdityaSomani My shaver is happy with 240/50 power despite being bought in the USA.  I do have to use a transformer for my electric toothbrush, though.

Comment: @LorenPechtel It depends on the power supply with your unit. All three electric beard trimmers I have used did not have a cross voltage compatible power supply. Albeit mine costed like 10 bucks each. :)

Comment: Many cheaper devices do not have such a cross voltage power supply, especially the ones with onboard power supply or no power supply at all. This includes, hair dryers, electric shavers, curling irons, electric toothbrushes, clothes irons etc.

Comment: @AdityaSomani Most of what you are listing are high power devices that require substantial wiring to be dual voltage.  However, a low power device that is going to convert the voltage anyway only needs to spec a few components bigger to be dual voltage.

Comment: @LorenPechtel A toothbrush requires relatively lesser power. While what you say might be true in general, there is no hard and fast rule and the OP must check in order to be sure.

Comment: Typically these days all electronic devices use a Switch Mode Power supply. Since SMPS require an active feedback loop to control the output voltage, they are typically able to deal with any mains voltages. However, electrical devices typically have no such things, and are typically tuned to the local mains voltage (and in some cases frequency).

Comment: @Aron That is also a factor, although I think the toothbrush must have had electronics in the charger.  In theory it could simply be a winding and nothing else (it's an induction device, no contact) but I would think that would waste a fair amount of power.

Comment: @AdityaSomani I fully agree you need to check but expect most of your stuff to work.

Comment: @LorenPechtel For me and three of my friends who did the exact same thing as the OP, only our laptop and phone chargers worked and nothing else. :( Maybe others don't seem to go thru this problem, but we did.

Comment: @LorenPechtel Also, please check underneath your razor if it is indeed made for operation underneath that voltage. If it is not designed for that voltage, you risk blowing it up when using on 240V, even though it will work, your battery can literally blow up.

Answer (score 24):

**Your laptop and phone chargers are designed to operate at a voltage between 100 - 240 V. Your electric shaver on the other hand may not be able to handle the different voltages** and will not work in the USA. Unfortunately for the electric shaver, you are stuck with 220V. The best way to make sure is to check on the device or its power supply. An example of how this is written is shown below. This is from a phone charger.

[image: Voltage range of appliance]

You should do this check for any electrical device you wish to carry. Devices with a **higher wattage requirement (>500W)** typically do not feature cross voltage usage due to a requirement of larger power supplies. Sometimes, smaller devices such as **electric toothbrushes, electric shavers, curling irons, hair dryers** must be checked as well. An induction cook-top for instance will almost never support cross voltages.

If you want to absolutely use your electric shaver in the US, you are looking at spending about $30 for a [step up/step down transformer](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001TPZ294) or a [special travel adapter for the same purpose (usually has a lower wattage rating)](http://www.bestekltd.com/Product_v60.html). **Without this, you can plug it, but your expensive device will not charge at an appropriate rate and you risk spoiling your battery due to overcharging, cutoffs and trickle rates.**

Also charging on a lower voltage for devices not designed for that voltage means waiting for 3 days for an electric shaver to charge. Believe me I have done this before.

Take note that you will require one which allows enough wattage for your device, so I do not recommend going for cheaper options.

If you don't wish to take your electric shaver, the other two devices are designed for operation on different voltages and will not have any issues.

Comment: Some electric shavers do work with both voltage ranges. It depends on the model. Laptops and phone chargers are indeed universal in my experience.

Comment: Most hotels have a special socket for shavers in toilets which have 110 and 220 volts. Also planes lavatories have that.

Comment: @MeNoTalk OP is travelling for a longer duration as a student. His worries would be more restricted to a general case.

Comment: @Gilles Indeed. But this is specific to the appliance, which I thought should be mentioned and not generalized.

Comment: @AdityaSomani I own a Moto G. The charger that I have reads - 100-240 V ~ 50-60 Hz (0.2 A). This would work in the States I guess!

Comment: @AnimeshPandey Indeed. As I mentioned, phones and laptops do not have issues usually.

Comment: Plus, that converter weighs almost 2 kg and it's probably not safe to take it to the bathroom (it's a shaver he wants it to use with).

Comment: @Szabolcs Please take a look at [this instead](http://www.bestekltd.com/Product_v60.html) as well. This would be easier to use but these ones tend to have a lower wattage rating and are not as sturdy as the one I linked earlier.

Answer (score 12):

You will only need an adapter for your plugs, as US sockets are not equipped for either of the two plugs used in India.  The adapters for the two pin Euro plugs are easy to find, the three pin a bit more challenging, but probably readily available in India before you leave.

If by chance you plan to be in the US for a couple of years of study, many laptop power supplies have a replaceable cable that goes from the power supply to the wall socket, so if it is a major brand you maybe able to find just a replacement cable in the states with the proper plug and not worry about forgetting or loosing your adapter.

For your mobile, replacement chargers are a dime a dozen in the box stores and electronic shops in the states.  Likewise USB ports that plug into wall sockets are widely available in the states, if your mobile or tablet or other toys use a usb power connector.

Comment: If the cable from between the mains socket and the power supply is detachable from the power supply, you should be able to buy a replacement, regardless of the brand. The connectors at the power-supply end of the cable will almost certainly be one of the Internatational Electrotechnical Commission's [IEC 60320 standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEC_60320#Appliance_Coupler_standard_sheets) standard connectors.

Answer (score 10):

As others said, most advanced electronic devices (laptop, phone & camera chargers) *typically* work with a wide range of voltages, 100-240 V (check the label!), so no voltage converter needed, only a wall plug adapter.

Some simpler appliances such as shavers, hairdryers, kitchen mixers, etc. don't usually work *automatically* with a wide range of voltages.  But many of them will have a switch that lets you switch between ~110 or ~220 V.  It'll look like a standard slot-type screw head and it will be labelled 110 / 220 V.  Check your device.

If the device doesn't work with 110 V, then in the vast majority of cases *it's not worth bothering with it.*  Voltage converters are unwieldy, inconvenient, heavy and might not be able to handle enough power to support your device (e.g. a hairdryer---a typical thing that doesn't work with multiple voltages---draws a *lot* of power).  **Stuff that doesn't support multiple voltages is almost always cheap enough that it's much better to buy it in the US.**  Even just considering the cost to carry it with you.

Answer (score 7):

Each charger/power supply/device will have an input voltage/frequency rating that you have to check individually. There is no generic " will/will not work" answer as all power supplies can be different. If the input rating is supported you can expect about the same performance as at your home location.

Generally there are two broad distinctions between power supplies: A [Switching power supply](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switching_power_supply) and a "classical" pure transformer based [Power Supply](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_supply).

The classical are often simpler and more robust, but are usually bulkier (due to the transformer) and only support a fixed ratio between input and output voltage (based on the transformer windings).

Switched power supplies work based on switching the input voltage on and off in high frequencies (and then smoothing the lower voltage output) and thus need only a smaller (and sometimes none at all) transformer, making it often even fit into a little bigger mains plug. Due to this way of constructing it, they support a wide range of input voltages and frequencies, while maintaining the same output voltage and current.

That said **you absolutely must check the rating written/imprinted on the power supplies you are going to use for your own and the devices safety**

For those that will not work with other than 220/230V input voltage, you should either use a converter (mentioned in other answers) that converts from 110V to 220V, or depending on the plug type that goes into the device, buy a universal adaptor based on a switching power supply that will have the same or a better output voltage/current rating of the device you need. *If you don't know if a given voltage/current rating is a sufficient one, go find someone who does (I have no idea if retail in india is a good idea to ask)*. If properly formulated in terms of electronic design, you might get more knowledge in answers from http://electronics.stackexchange.com